# Which of these conditions on continuity imply that two topologies are equal?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}'$ are two topologies on $X$. Determine whether or not the given condition implies $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T}'$. If not, give a counterexample. If so, prove it.
>
> 1. For every finite topological space $W$, $f : W \to X$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}$ iff it is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}'$.
> 2. For every finite topological space $Y$, $f : X \to Y$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}$ iff it is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}'$.
> 3. For every Hausdorff space $Y$, $f : X \to Y$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}$ iff it is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}'$.

Comment: Some of us got together and worked on 1a, we barely cracked it after 8 hours of work but nothing much after that.

Comment: Well ok, so what did you get about 1a, and how?

Comment: I was trying to prove that the condition does imply that the two topologies are equal and my classmates were trying to prove otherwise. I only heard from them a couple hours ago saying that they barely made progress. We have 8 more problems for our homework so most of us moved on to the other problems.

Comment: Yunus I too struggled badly with my topology homework when I first got it, but you aren't telling me _what_ you concluded, so that I can tell you if its right, or nudge you in the right direction without flat out giving you the answer.

Comment: I put this question up here for an answer. I understand that you want us to figure this out by ourselves but we spend 15 hrs a week on our regular topology homework. This homework is exceptionally hard compared to this previous ones. The top guy in our class spends 4 hours on the regular homeworks. He spent 8 hrs on 1a

Comment: If time permits, I feel you should have a few minutes break. Good luck

Comment: I upvoted, the comments show research effort, which deeply impressed me.

Answer (score 3):

Very nice problem, here are some hints!

1) For instance, take a set $X$ with $T$ the discrete topology and $T'$ a topology such that the induced topology on any finite subset of $X$ is discrete (example?). Notice that in general $f:X_1\to X_2$ is continuous iff $f:X_1\to f(X_1)$ is, where $f(X_1)\subseteq X_2$ has the discrete topology.

2) Take $A\subseteq X$ open in ${T}$, $W=\{0,1\}$, $f=\chi_A$, choose the appropriate topology on $W$ (not much to choose!)

3) A finite Hausdorff set has the discrete topology (why?). If $X$ is connected, $f(X)$ is connected, so what are the continuous maps $X\to Y$ in this case?

Comment: We have yet to cover connectedness in our topology class. For the last question, Y isn't necessarily finite.

Comment: Also, can you please indicate true or false for all of them because I'm having some difficulty understanding which direction these are going.

Comment: @YunusSyed More hints. 2 is true, 1 and 3 are false. For 3 there is a counterexample with finite $X$